# Unity Spawn Object Using Couroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a capsule which is my character and i need my capsule to spawn a sphere that will smoothly move to positions i set.
There is code but it moves my character and i dont know how to spawn object in position of character and move it to another position

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PingPongWithDelay());
}


private IEnumerator MoveFromTo(Vector3 startPosition, Vector3 endPosition, float time)
{
    var currentTime = 0f;
    while (currentTime < time) 
    {
        
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, 1 - (time - currentTime) / time);
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    
    transform.position = endPosition;
}

private IEnumerator PingPongWithDelay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return MoveFromTo(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), 2f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        yield return MoveFromTo(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), 2f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well kind of the same way but move the spawned sphere instead of the character?

Comment: Yes exactly. Do u know how to do this?

Comment: Yes .. but I think you could figure it out yourself ;) you already have examples for moving from one point to another ... so all that's left to do for you is connect the dots and a) store a reference to the Instantiated object (`var sphere = Instantiate(spherePrefab);`) and then start a coroutine passing this sphere in as parameter and use it for the moveFromto instead of `transform`

Comment: I’m new to unity. And for me is so complicated. Where should I write sphere and how to assign MoveFromTo to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said you already have your template routines you just have to use them like you want e.g.

```
public void SpawnSphere(Vector3 startPosition, Vector3 targetPosition, float duration)
{
    var sphere = Instantiate(spherePrefab);

    StartCorouine (MoveFromTo(sphere.transform, startPosition, targetPosition, duration);
}



private IEnumerator MoveFromTo(Transform obj, Vector3 startPosition, Vector3 endPosition, float time)
{
    obj.position = startPosition;
    for (var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < time; timePassed += Time.deltaTime) 
    {   
        obj.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, timePassed / time);
        yield return null;
    }

    obj.position = endPosition;
}
```